# Add and delete function malfunctioning in Linked list

Tags: c, function, linked-list

I want to make a management system using linked list in C, where it stores student record, so that it could be searched and deleted. I am programming on devC editor.

My all functions are working except the `delAt` function. Whenever I execute this function, my program hangs. Another problem is, if I want to execute the `addAt` function more than once, that means if I choose "option 1" more than one time, the program hangs. Although it doesn't hang when I select "option 1" only 1 time.

Following is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dos.h>

struct stud
{
    int rn, id, ph[15];
    char add[30], na[20], d[15], in[5];
    struct stud *next;
} *h = NULL, *p, *q, *t, *ts;

void add()
{
    p =(struct stud*)malloc(sizeof(struct stud*));
    printf("\nEnter the Initials of Student : ");
    scanf("%s", &p->in);
    printf("\nEnter the Last Name of Student : ");
    scanf("%s", &p->na);
    printf("\nEnter the ID of Student : ");
    scanf("%d", &p->id);
    printf("\nEnter the Roll No. of Student : ");
    scanf("%d", &p->rn);
    printf("\nEnter the Ph No. of Student : ");
    scanf("%d", &p->ph);
    printf("\nEnter the Address of Student : ");
    scanf("%s", &p->add);
    printf("\nEnter the D.O.B. of Student(dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
    scanf("%s", &p->d);

    p->next = NULL;

    if (h == NULL)
    {
        h=p;
    }
    else
    {
        q = h;
        while (q->next != NULL)
        {
            q = q->next;
        }
        q->next = p;
    }
    ts++;
}

void delAt(int r)
{
    q=h;
    r=x;
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty");
    }

    while (q->rn != r - 1)
    {
        q = q->next;
    }

    p = q->next;
    q->next = p->next;
    free(p);
    printf("\n\nRecord Deleted.");
}

void main()
{
    int ch = 0, r;
    char ni[5];
    while(ch != 8)
    {
        printf("1.Add the Record.\n\n2.Add Record at Locn.\n\n3.Delete Record.");
        printf("\n\n4.Modify Record.\n\n5.Search Record.\n\n6.Sort Records.");
        printf("\n\n7.Display\n\n8.Exit");
        printf("\n\nEnter the Choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                add();
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nEnter the Roll No. : ");
                scanf("%d",&r);
                delAt(r);
                break;

            case 7:
                disp();
                break;
        }

        ch++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're getting ahead of yourself here. There are many problems with the code, for example your use of almost only global variables instead of passing arguments and using local variables, or your use of the address-of operator `&` to get the address of arrays (which works but is semantically wrong), or you including obsolete and non-standard header files that aren't even used, or you allocating much to little memory for the structure. I suggest you find a new and modern C beginners book (or two), and start all over, carefully doing all exercises.

Comment: `r=x;` ?  what is that ? Please make sure the posted code can compile

Comment: While at it, use some readable style when rewriting: **One** variable / struct member declaration per line, **meaningful** variable names (never just a single letter), same for functions (what's `disp()`? dispose? dispatch?)

Comment: You ask about a function `addat`  but there is no such function in the posted code!

Comment: ... and you call `disp()` but there is no code for `disp()`. Are you sure you posted the correct version?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you expect the `delat` function to do. Can you describe it further? Anyway, have you considered what will happen if `delat` is called with a value that doesn't have a match in the linked list?

Comment: delAt means delete, disp =display

Comment: the header files: `conio.h` and `dos.h`  are not portable.  Strongly suggest not using them.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3)  use meaningful variable names.  variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both)  names like 'p' 'h' 'q' are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the input format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any possible buffer overflow

Comment: regardless of what visual studio will allow, the return type from `main()` is always `int`, not `void`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  ( Note:  visual studio uses a different set of options to enable warnings )

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does not cleanly compile!  Please correct and repost.

Here is a list of the messages output by the C compiler:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)

untitled.c: In function ‘add’:
untitled.c:18:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[5]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%s", &p->in);
        ~^   ~~~~~~

untitled.c:20:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%s", &p->na);
        ~^   ~~~~~~

untitled.c:26:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[15]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%d", &p->ph);
        ~^   ~~~~~~

untitled.c:28:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%s", &p->add);
        ~^   ~~~~~~~

untitled.c:30:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[15]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%s", &p->d);
        ~^   ~~~~~

untitled.c: In function ‘delAt’:
untitled.c:53:7: error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 r=x;
   ^

untitled.c:53:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

untitled.c: At top level:
untitled.c:70:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main()
 ^~~~

untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:94:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘disp’; did you mean ‘div’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             disp();
             ^~~~
             div

untitled.c:73:10: warning: unused variable ‘ni’ [-Wunused-variable]
 char ni[5];
      ^~
```

Compilation failed.